# Compiling errors at API level 28

Tags: android, compilation, crash, admob, apk

I'm trying to compile an .apk from source code at API level 28 (compileSdkVersion 28). The app compiles fine but after installation it crashes. My app has Admob Ads in the UI itself on various pages.

Here's my project-level build.gradle -

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Here's my app-level build.gradle -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "****APP_ID****"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here's the Ad code from my AndroidManifest.xml -

```
 <application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="*****ADMOB-ID*****"/>
</application>
```

Here's the Ad code from my MainActivity.java

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


      private LinearLayout linear1;
      private AdView adview1;
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         initialize(_savedInstanceState);
         initializeLogic();
         MobileAds.initialize(this, "*****ADMOB-ID*****");
     }
```

I'm relatively new to Android coding. What might be the problem?

Comment: add your error log

Comment: Yes I have the same Problem, When I compile with targetSdkVersion 26 the App runs well. But when I change to targetSdkVersion 28 The App crashes after some secounds. When I set debug break points, and step through the code the App crashes one time there and at next try on an other step. Programming is not fun anymore. Thats google live. No respect and and not backwards compatible.

Comment: The next Problem is that Google only accept PlayStore updates for Apps which are generated for targetSdkVersion 28. Because of the Bug in targetSdkVersion 28, you can never update your app. Chears

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable `org.apache.http.legacy` from your application so add below lines in manifest

```
 <uses-library
  android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
  android:required="false" />
```

remove **useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'** from gradle

If you are using any http url in your application, [refer this](https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6)

Comment: Hi Rajasekaran. There is no error log since the apk file is getting compiled without any glitch. It's only after the installation that app crashes on opening.

Comment: @pinaka87 ii still app crashed?

Comment: Yes it's still crashing

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace your application ID

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "****APP_ID****"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

you have to add version

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
```

you have to add admob app id here

```
   <application>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="*****ADMOB-ID*****"/>
</application>
```

and here

```
  MobileAds.initialize(this, "*****ADMOB-ID*****");
```

first try to fix these errors

Comment: Hi Reddy.  The application I'd and admob id are in place. I've just used the ****ID**** to hide my codes. And I've just tried using com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0       ...... it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

If you use an url in your code, just use "https://theTargetUrl..." in your url instead of "http://theTargetUrl..."  and that's all!
It should work like a charm.